# Matmul Eror shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

### Defining weights as variables in a linear model

I'm new in tensorflow , and i ran this code using `tf.matmul`, 
At first- I didn't understand why the shape in `matmul` is not good.- i fixed it with another [] int the definition of the variable.

now- i don't understand why it's still doesn't work.

```js
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable([[.3]], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([[-.3]], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(linear_model, {x: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]}))
```

```css
C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe "C:/Users/hagayj/OneDrive/לימודים/untitled1/Defining weights as variables in a linear model.py"
2018-11-05 20:21:31.580447: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1292, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1277, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1367, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,4], In[1]: [1,1]
  [[{{node MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Variable/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<encoding error>", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 887, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1110, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1286, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1308, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,4], In[1]: [1,1]
  [[{{node MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Variable/read)]]

Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:
  File "<encoding error>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2053, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 4856, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3272, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\hagayj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1768, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,4], In[1]: [1,1]
  [[{{node MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Variable/read)]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi. What is the point of using matmul in your code, if the numbers are only scalars? If you use tf.multiply instead, it will work.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do with `matmul`? `W` should be two-dimensional for a matrix multiplication, and won't work for scalar values or 1D vectors, as already mentioned.

Comment: i got it as a 'must have' function to use.. ft.matmul, and the example was those variables...
it should work also on constant... no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it should work if you add additional brackets:

```
W = tf.Variable([[.3]], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([[-.3]], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
...
print(sess.run(linear_model, {x: [[1],[2],[3],[4]]}))
```

Comment: Write it like me, this part: {x: [[1],[2],[3],[4]]}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're using `matmul` to multiply one-dimensional vectors.  If you check the shape of `W` by `W.get_shape()`, it will return (1,) while it should be a 2D matrix of shape (1,1).  You can do this by simply adding brackets: `W = tf.Variable([[.3]], tf.float32)`.

Doing this for `x` as well (`sess.run(linear_model, {x: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]})`) creates a (1,4) matrix.  But if you multiply `x` and `W`, you will get an error because you are trying to multiply a (1,4) matrix with a (1,1) matrix so they are incompatible (the second value in the first matrix shape needs to be the same as the first value in the second matrix shape).  Instead, you would need to take a transpose of `x` so that you are multiplying a (4,1) matrix with a (1,1) matrix.  This can be done by using the `transpose_a=True` flag in `matmul`.  Here's the final code that would run without errors:

```
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable([[.3]], tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([[-.3]], tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = tf.matmul(x, W, transpose_a=True) + b

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(linear_model, {x: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]}))
```